# iphone, Electron Microscope can see the ROM cell states

Tags: memory

Just one bit gets toggled when the passcode is correct.  Why not just toggle that one charged/discharged cell?  Determine that bit through experimentation with an electron microscope.

Answer (score 1):

> Just one bit gets toggled when the passcode is correct.

No. It is having a different code path if the passcode is correct which involves lots of other bit. And even if this would only be one bit: how do you find exactly this one bit you would need to toggle? It is not that memory layout is that predictable so that you could easily find the needed bit. And experimentation changes the state of the system (like adding to the maxfail counter), which means that it would not be always the same bit you would need to toggle. And after only a few number of tests the phone might even wipe itself because you've had too much failed attempts.

Comment: ...plus there's a *lot* of bits. A **LOT**.

Answer (score 0):

One word: **encryption.**

More words: Your assumption is incorrect. Since about 2014, the data on iPhones is encrypted *by default*.

If the data were unencrypted, you could indeed skip the question "is the passcode correct Y/N?" (which is, for further reading, called Discretionary Access Control). IRL, this would be a big padlock on the gate, requiring you to set the right passcode - or pry it off with a big enough crowbar, or get in through a window.

For encrypted data, you would only get a big blob of random-looking data out, as it's encrypted *using* the passcode as a part of the key (a device-unique set of numbers is another part). Therefore, without actually knowing the correct passcode, you can't see the data. IRL, this would be a secret colored filter for viewing a page printed with multi-colored inks: even if you actually *have* the page, you need to know *precisely* what filter to use, else you'd only see a big, useless mess.